# Creating Multiple Forms By Combining Multiple Projects

Tags: c#, winforms, projects-and-solutions

Assume that I have a project that contains two buttons on it. Each buttons generate a custom form. I wrote both forms manually. But I wonder, is there a way that I can make these forms by using toolbox in different projects and combine them in one solution.  I mean,  when I press a button I want to call another project.

And finally if such a solution exists, is it proper way to make programs like this , or is it better to create forms manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a form from another project (if we are talking about VS project) if it is public. You need to add reference to the project where this form is "placed" to the project where the call is made.

Of course, you can create forms manually, but you can as well create new windows form and add controls to it via designer.

And about the proper way. If you need the same form to be called from different projects, then, yes, keeping in in some third project is alright.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can invoke the forms even if they are in different projects. But you need to have references to that projects and to have defined a proper using statements.